# Copy text fom one textbox to another with some restriction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two text boxes.What I want to do is while i Write something in one text box it should be copied to the other(i am able to do so).But my requirement is if i write anything else rather then a-z or A-Z or 0-9 then it should not copied to the second text box.
my html

```
<textarea name="source" id="src1" cols="150" rows="20"   onkeyup="showRelated(event)">
<textarea name="source2" id="src2" cols="150" rows="20" >
```

my js

```
function showRelated(e) {

        $("#src2").val($("#src1").val()) ;
       }
```

Let me explain little bit more,Suppose i write LO^&1VE then in the second text box LOVE should be copied only.now if i go further like adding more LO^&1VE C**V then in the second text box LOVE CV should be appaer only.Can any one suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regular expression [^a-zA-Z0-9] to check for or replace characters that are not alphanumeric

```
function showRelated(){
    $("#src2").val( $("src1").val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,"") );
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function showRelated(e){
    $("#src2").val( $("#src1").val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,"") );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="src1" onkeyup="showRelated(event);"></textarea>
<textarea id="src2"></textarea>
```

Comment: but it replaces whatever there earlier in the second text box.i want every alphabets and number  written in the 1st text box to the second text box.According to your code if i write anything it replaces the earlier thing.i don't want to replace.Let me explain little bit more,Suppose i write LO^&1VE then in the second text box LOVE should be copied only.now if i go further like adding more LO^&1VE C**V then in the second text box LOVE CV should be copied only.

Answer (score 0):

Rather brutal way of doing it but here goes

```
function showRelated(e) {
    var text=$("#src1").val().split("");
    var pattern=/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
    var nStr='';
    for (var i=0;i<text.length;i++) {
        if (pattern.test(text[i])) {
            nStr+=text[i];
        }
    }
    $("#src2").val(nStr);
}
```

Basically this will check each char follows your criteria and then puts it in if it does.